# Take a screenshot from a widget Android

Tags: android, widget, screenshot

Is it possible to take a screenshot from a View inside a widget? I'm developing an app and I managed to take it from an Activity (even if, I don't know why, the quality is extremely poor); now as this app has a widget too I'd like to preserve this feature inside it, let's say with a button.

The problem is I've read that it is not possible to get something from a widget, that is to say widgets have only setters not getters. Is it correct? Is it really that I cannot take an element from a widget? If so, do you have some particular advice to solve the issue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

What if you start an activity that is completely transparent, when interacting with the widget. When created, all the user will be able to see is the previous screen (their homescreen, with the widget they just pressed). 
Since you can take a screenshot of an activity, taking a screenshot of a transparent activity, means that you'll capture what's behind it, right?

Comment: mmmm this is a good idea... the only problem is that I need to get only a View from the widget, not the entire screen so the I need to get it from the widget